# drop down menus on tablet pcs

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

Hi is there a good way to implement drop downs so that they're functional on tablet pc's, either with css or javascript.

Obviously there are workarounds such as including alternative navigation areas, I just wondered if there was a way to get them working.

Comment: There are some excellent drop downs available on code canyon which work on tablets, ipads, cellphones etc http://codecanyon.net search css3 menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea for jQuery solution for iPads and iPhones based on detecting userAgent (uses click instead on mouseover):

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) ||(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {  
    $(".link").click(function(){  
        $(".submenu").show();  
       //you can insert other stuff here  
       return false;  
    });  
}
```